# Ставится ли точка после прямой речи перед словами автора?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Слышала о правиле, которое формулируется примерно так: "Если слова автора не поясняют прямую речь (то есть не содержат глаголов, отвечающих за "говорение"), а идут как бы параллельно с речью, то они пишутся с большой буквы".

В примерах к этому правилу всегда встречаются только предложения, где прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным или вопросительным знаком. А что делать, если там запятая? Возможна ли вместо неё точка? И в каких конкретно случаях пишется с большой буквы? Когда в словах автора нет глагола, отвечающего за процесс говорения, или только когда в них говорится о чём-то совсем отвлечённом?

Вот пример из художественной книги, исходя из которого нужно ставить точку: "Оставь его. Они правы. – Голос его упал. – Если «Королева» взорвется, дело не обойдется только кораблем и доком". В словаре Розенталя о таком случае вообще ни слова. Значит ли это, что слова автора всё-таки пишутся с маленькой буквы всегда?

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего точка после прямой речи ставится при прямом порядке слов.

Я позволю себе процитировать свой же давний ответ с другого сайта:

**вопрос**

**[Напомните пожалуйста, после тире в данном случае надо писать с маленькой буквы?](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/167710986)**

> – Хм… – задумчиво пытался он подобрать правильные слова...

**ответ**

В приведённом примере всё верно, после прямой речи - строчная. Но отнюдь не всегда. Зависит от порядка слов:

а) "Хм… " – задумчиво пытался он подобрать правильные слова.
Ср. : "Хм..." – Он задумчиво пытался подобрать правильные слова.

Тут "хм" отображает попытку подобрать некие слова, замешательство;

б) и от того, сохраняет ли глагол после прямой речи "значение высказывания".

Ср. : "Хм..." – Он уныло уставился в окно.

Тут "хм" не соотносится с унылостью или созерцанием пейзажа.

Правило никак не найду, но примерно так:

Со строчной пишутся авторские слова, если они содержат в себе глагол со значением речи или мысли (сказать, спросить, ответить, подтвердить, начать, продолжать, прервать, подумать, вспомнить и др.) либо же близкое по значению имя существительное (вопрос, ответ, слова, восклицание, голос, звук, шепот, крик, мысль и т. п.), также в тех случаях, когда в функции слов, вводящих прямую речь, используются глаголы, обозначающие чувства говорящего, его внутреннее состояние (обрадоваться, огорчиться, обидеться, ужаснуться и др.), а также глаголы, обозначающие мимику, жесты, движения (улыбнуться, усмехнуться, рассмеяться, нахмуриться, вздохнуть, вскочить, подойти, подбежать и т. п.).

– Ничего, до свадьбы заживет, – глянул он с усмешкой.

– Опять двойку получил? – нахмурилась мать.

– Неужели это правда? – ужаснулась Катя.

(При прямом порядке слов после прямой речи в тех же примерах - трёх последних - авторская речь будет начинаться с прописной.)

---

Можете почитать ещё пять ответов на этот вопрос. Среди них - точку зрения Искусственного Интеллекта Маши, опровергающего мой ответ.

Comment: А о прописных? Человек спрашивает: «А что делать, если там запятая? Возможна ли вместо неё точка? И в каких конкретно случаях пишется с большой буквы?»

Comment: Запятую меняем на *требуемый* знак. Конкретно: в случае прямого порядка слов.

Comment: То есть в данном случае возможна точка?

Comment: Если мы о *Голос его упал*, то да, точка после *Они правы*.

Answer (score 1):

Да, такая пунктуация вполне возможна.
Вот правило:
Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой **отдельное предложение**, то они пишутся с прописной буквы (**— П! — А.**):
*— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.*
[**§ 49. Прямая речь перед словами автора. Примечание 2**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)

Смысл фразы "отдельное предложение" состоит в том, что из прямой речи и слов автора невозможно составить "общее" предложение — они грамматически между собой не связаны (части "оторваны" друг от друга и независимы по смыслу; глаголов, обозначающих речь или чувства, нет).
Сравните:
1. — Возьми зонтик, на улице дождь, — сказала мама и закрыла окно.
2. — Возьми зонтик, на улице дождь. — Мама закрыла окно.

> — Оставь его. Они правы. — Голос его упал. — Если «Королева» взорвется, дело не обойдется только кораблем и доком ([А. Нортон. Подчеркнуто звездами](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=10799&p=33)).

Все правильно: точка после прямой речи; слова автора — с прописной (**— П. — А. — П.**).

Вот похожее предложение:

*— Она купалась здесь, в этом затоне. — **Голос его упал до шепота.** — Никогда не боялась, что подсмотрит кто-то. Человеческие законы для нее ничего не значили.*
Т. Корсакова. Алое на черном

Обратите внимание, что при наличии т. н. глаголов "говорения" после прямой речи ставится запятая (или другой знак), а слова автора начинаются со строчной буквы (**— П! — а. — П!**):

*— Гребля! — **сказал он упавшим голосом.** — Теперь молитесь богу, пассажиры!*
К. Паустовский. Далекие годы