# Точка при разрыве прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Возможен ли следующий вариант оформления прямой речи?

П. — А. — П.

Нигде в интернете не нашла такого варианта, но моя учительница с огромным стажем говорит, что такой вариант возможен, если в первой «П» находится законченное предложение. Хочется знать точно.

Спасибо!

Comment: И точка может быть, и вопр. знак, и восклицательный. Можно посмотреть вот здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9/441617#441617 (Может ли авторский текст, разделяющий прямую речь, начинаться с прописной?)

Answer (score 3):

Конечно же, такое оформление прямой речи даже очень возможно.
Не буду пересказывать объяснения (тема многажды обсуждалась на форуме), отмечу только, что в школьной программе эта пунктуация рассматривается вскользь, мимоходом, а вот в добротной, большой литературе без нее — никуда.
И слова автора, и собственно прямая речь могут состоять из нескольких предложений, могут, кроме точки, иметь и вопросительный знак, и восклицательный, и многоточие.

Вот примеры (самое начало романа Рекса Стаута «И быть подлецом»).

> — На меня наводят уныние цифры. — Я наклонился, чтобы перебросить форму 1040 через полированную крышку его стола. — Это от тринадцатого марта. Четыре тысячи триста двенадцать долларов и шестьдесят восемь центов плюс четыре квартальных взноса. Таким образом, нам необходимо послать форму 1040—ЕС, приложив к ней чек на десять тысяч долларов. — Я переплёл пальцы рук за головой и спросил с улыбкой:
> — Ну как, действительно уныло? [**— П. — А. — П. — А: — П?**]
> <...>
> — Прекрасно. — Вульф глубоко вздохнул, посидел минуту, затем выпрямился в кресле. — Чёрт побери! Было время, когда мне хватало тысячи динаров в год. Соедини меня с мистером Ричардсом из Федеральной радиовещательной корпорации. [**— П. — А. — П.**]
> <...>
> — О! — Наступила пауза. Голос Ричардса обычно был дружелюбным и даже тёплым. Сейчас он немного изменился. — Каким образом вы оказались к этому причастны? [**— П! — А. — П?**]
> <...>
> — Меня зовут Дебора Коппел. — Она протянула руку. — Мы здесь и самих себя иногда не замечаем. [**— П. — А. — П.**]

[Ставится ли точка после прямой речи перед словами автора?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435615/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/436557#436557)
[Может ли авторский текст, разделяющий прямую речь, начинаться с прописной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9/441617#441617)