# Прямая речь, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Вот пример:
— Вам его не достать, — шепчет кто-то.
— Идем. Хватит. — Женщина кивает на выход.

Почему во втором предложении стоит точка после слова "хватит", а слово "женщина" написано с заглавной буквы? Разве по схемам прямой речи не должно быть так: **— П, — а.**

Или здесь типа это уже не прямая речь (то есть нет дополнений вроде "говорит"), а описание действия, потому так написано предложение? Я искала в интернете правила при прямой речи, но везде написана та схема, которую я написала, нигде не видела такую: **— П. — А.**

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/Может-ли-авторский-текст-разделяющий-прямую-речь-начинаться-с-прописной

Answer (score 2):

— Вам его не достать, — шепчет кто-то.
— Идем. Хватит. — Женщина кивает на выход.

Да, такая пунктуация возможна (**— П. — А.**). С глаголами **кивать** и **кивнуть** постановка знаков зависит от ситуации.

**I.** Если предполагается, что кто-то говорит и кивает в этот момент (мы знаем, что действия происходят одновременно, или чувствуем это по контексту), то, конечно, лучше слова автора начинать со **строчной** буквы.

**II.** Если же человек сначала произносит фразу и только потом кивает (в сторону кого-то или чего-то), то **прописная** буква в словах автора вполне уместна (в этом случае авторские слова грамматически не связаны с прямой речью).

Можно сравнить две различные ситуации.

1. > — Хотите кофе? — предложила хозяйка. — Или, может быть, лучше чаю?
   >   — Спасибо. Не откажусь, — согласился Журавель.
   >   — Вы присаживайтесь, товарищ сержант, — **женщина кивнула на кресло.**
2. > — Но к западу от Вилайета не найдется коня, который мог бы сравниться с моим Иремом. — **И мужчина кивнул** на высокого тонконогого жеребца, стоявшего позади него.

Некоторые рассуждения и примеры есть вот здесь:
[Может ли авторский текст, разделяющий прямую речь, начинаться с прописной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9?rq=1)
[Слова автора — прописная/строчная буква](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460732/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0/460739#460739)
[Ставится ли точка после прямой речи перед словами автора?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435615/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Интересные у вас примеры, но у меня к ним такие замечания. Персонажи кивают и говорят  наверняка одновременно. Но автору в первом случае захотелось использовать действие вместо слов автора (произношение с короткой паузой). Но вот запись мне кажется неудачной, лучше так: — Вы присаживайтесь, товарищ сержант, — кивнула  она на кресло. То есть важно глагол поставить сразу после прямой речи. А иначе лучше разделить предложения: — Вы присаживайтесь, товарищ сержант. Женщина кивнула на кресло.

Comment: Да, конечно, можно и перестроить. Авторская пунктуация — вещь непредсказуемая. Иногда до ненормальности. Вчера отвечала на вопрос (искала примеры), и попалось вот ЭТО: _Только, когда, у крыльца, кто-то громко, заявил, о своем присутствии, громко спросив: «Есть – кто, живой?», она, отвлеклась, от экономических расчетов_ (М. М. Вербицкий. Тропа тунеядцев. Из жизни контрразведчиков). Я давно не видела столько сумасшедших запятых. (Ссылка не влезает. Можно найти по предложению.)

Comment: @Sharon, абсолютно согласен с вашими замечаниями.

Comment: Да, существуют какие-то правила замены глагола речи глаголом действия.   нельзя это делать чисто формально, должна просматриваться сочетаемость.

Answer (score 1):

Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы:

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.

Answer (score 1):

Оформление верное: ***— Идем. Хватит. — Женщина кивает на выход.***

Я дополню ответ Сержа, в котором объясняется этот вариант.

1) **Вот ссылка на справочник  Розенталя** (интересно, какого он года): https://modernlib.net/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_17

2) **Вот ответ Грамоты.ру**

Вопрос № 281073
Добрый день!
В справочнике Розенталя есть интересное примечание по поводу прямой речи перед словами автора.
А именно:
Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы:
***— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.***

Но ни в "Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации (1956)", ни в справочнике под редакцией Лопатина ничего подобного не нашла.

Прошу разъяснить этот вопрос. Действительно ли бывают случаи, когда после прямой речи ставится точка и слова автора пишутся с прописной буквы? И когда же слова автора считаются отдельным предложением? А ещё скажите, пожалуйста, каким справочником нужно руководствоваться в спорных случаях?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

**Такое оформление прямой речи возможно.** Слова автора названы отдельным предложением, т. к. в них нет глагола речи (сказал, закричал, воскликнул и т. д.). **Правда, встречается такое оформление нечасто, поэтому многие справочники об этом правиле не вспоминают.** Оно приведено в пособии Д. Э. Розенталя «Пунктуация», это очень подробный справочник, в нем рассмотрены многие частные случаи, о которых не говорится в других справочных изданиях.

3) Комментарий.

Правила Розенталя и Лопатина содержат описание только основных (базовых) схем. Эта тема, которая нуждается в **значительном дополнении.** Причем нуждается уже давно, а в настоящее время особенно.

В литературе появилось множество вариантов оформления прямой речи персонажей, описания **их действий** при этом, а также различные варианты **деления на абзацы**, но при этом они остаются **ненормированными.** Практически материал по этой теме отсутствует, дан в минимальном количестве, а частично, может быть, и устарел.

Вот Грамота.ру пишет, что "встречается такое оформление нечасто". Интересно, они вообще-то читают современную литературу? Или хотя бы классическую, например:

***— Что такое Базаров? — Аркадий усмехнулся. — Хотите, дядюшка, я вам скажу, что он, собственно, такое?***

Честно говоря, такая ситуация вызывает у меня недоумение. Эта область правописания вообще-то регулируется какими-нибудь современными правилами? **Что сейчас используют** редакторы при оформлении печатных изданий?

Comment: Учебник 2007года.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Но это уже переиздание, а сам-то Розенталь в каком году его писал? Когда учебник впервые вышел?

Comment: Да, это переиздание. Но есть другое пособие. Былинский К. И., Розенталь Д. Э. Трудные случаи пунктуации. – М., 1959.  П р и м е ч а н и е 3. Если авторские слова, стоящие
после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы.
Например:
— Ребята, машина приехала! — И Коля побежал дальше, чтобы успеть предупредить всех.
'Если же они продолжают предложение, начавшееся
перед прямой речью (см. § 118), то.первое слово пишется
со строчной буквы. Например:
. Коля крикнул: — Ребята, машина приехала! — и побе-
жал дальше, чтобы успеть предупредить всех.

Comment: Кстати, это вы когда-то дали ссылку на это пособие в одном из своих ответов.

Comment: Да, я помню, но сразу не нашла.  А вообще эту "школу"  на форуме раз пять-шесть цитировали, если не больше.  Других-то правил нет, вот все на нее и ссылаются.

Comment: Sharon, на форуме мне довелось увидеть только вашу ссылку.

Comment: Я  ищу так: копирую всё предложение про школу (можно еще добавить сочетание "прямая речь"),  Потом как будто задаю такой новый вопрос. Система сообщает, что были подобные вопросы и указывает ссылки.

Comment: А-а, вы имели в виду пример про школу из справочнике. Да, я много раз видел. И сам приводил этот пример. Я вас сперва неправильно понял.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, от "школы" уже устала, просмотрев все эти примеры. Такая моральная усталость: опять эта школа, слышать про нее больше не могу. Это уже, наверное, клиника, у психологов надо спросить.

Comment: Есть и другие примеры.

Comment: У Розенталя? И какие же?

Comment: См. комментарий.

Comment: А, про Колю, но он не намного лучше. Что они у него всё бегают и кого-то предупреждают.   Надо бы из классики примеры привести, высокохудожественное что-нибудь.

Comment: http://www.liveexpert.ru/link?https://popravilam.com/blog/154-nestandartnoe-oformlenie-pryamoj-rechi.html